# If Else statement logic execution

Tags: java

The line with the problem is. This line should check if the 3rd index contains character and it should not contain the words north and america.

```
   else if ( salida[3].matches("[a-zA-Z]+") && !salida[3].equals("North") ) { // not working correctly
                    if (  !salida[3].equals("America")) {
                    salida1 = salida1 + salida[0] + " " + salida[1] + " " + salida[2] + " " + salida[3] +  ",";
```

The code above should run for the 4th line of the array data below

```
[United, States, 1,527,664, 90,978, North, America]
[Canada, 77,002, 5,782, North, America]
[Turks, and, Caicos, 12, 1, North, America]
[St., Vincent, &, Grenadines, 17, 0, North, America]
```

this is the string output I'm currently getting which doesn't add the 3rd index of the array to the string

```
United States,Canada ,Mexico ,Dominican Republic,Panama ,Honduras ,Guatemala ,Cuba ,El Salvador,Costa Rica,Jamaica ,Haiti ,Martinique ,Guadeloupe ,Bermuda ,Trinidad and,Aruba ,Bahamas ,Cayman Islands,Barbados ,Sint Maarten,Saint Martin,Nicaragua ,Antigua and,Grenada ,Belize ,Saint Lucia,St. Vincent,Curaçao ,Dominica ,Saint Kitts,Turks and,Montserrat ,Greenland ,British Virgin,Saint Barthelemy,Caribbean Netherlands,Anguilla ,Saint Pierre,
```

Input country to display data:

This is my entire code

````
public String setCountriesList() {
    String salida1 = "";
    try {
        Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/countries-where-coronavirus-has-spread/").get();
        Elements tr = doc.select("tr");
        String [] na = {"north", "america"};
        for (int i = 0; i < tr.size(); i++) {
            if (tr.get(i).text().contains("North America")) {
                String[] salida = tr.get(i).text().split(" ");  
                System.out.println(salida[3].contains("North") + " and " + salida[3].contains("America") );
                System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(salida));                                                //split salida to country, number ,number in array
                if ( salida[1].matches("[a-zA-Z]+")) {
                    salida1 = salida1 + salida[0] + " " + salida[1] + ",";          
                }
                else if ( salida[2].matches("[a-zA-Z]+")) {
                    salida1 = salida1 + salida[0] + " " + salida[1] + " " + salida[2] +  ",";           
                }
                else if ( salida[3].matches("[a-zA-Z]+") && !salida[3].equals("North") ) { // not working correctly
                    if (  !salida[3].equals("America")) {
                    salida1 = salida1 + salida[0] + " " + salida[1] + " " + salida[2] + " " + salida[3] +  ",";             
                }}
         ```




                else {
                     salida1 = salida1 + salida[0] + " ,";
                }

            }
        }
        return salida1;
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println("error");
        return "error";
    }
}
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that the names of the countries contain a comma "," which is your separator character. You need to find a way to have the country name within the same index 0, or at least wrap the country name in quotes "", so that "North" is effectively index 3. In the examples above "North" was only index 3 for Canada.

Comment: Can you recommend a regex that splits to 
[United States, (1,527,664), (90,978), North American]

Comment: Why don't you iterate over the TDs in each of those TRs instead? That'd give you this for free.

Comment: Elements td = tr.select("td"); then iterate over this one. It will give you exactly what you need I reckon.

Comment: I'm not sure how to do that with TD

Comment: [North America]
error
error
Input country to display data:
It shows up this, I'm pretty bad with knowing which tag to take

Comment: See my comment above: Elements td = tr.select("td")

Comment: Ok, here's the full code from the tr for line showing you how you can iterate the columns:     `for (int i = 0; i < tr.size(); i++) {

                Element row = tr.get(i);

                Elements columns = row.select("td");

                if (columns.size() == 0) { // header row
                    continue;
                }

                for (int j = 0; j < columns.size(); j++) {
                    Element currentTd = columns.get(j);
                    System.out.println("Value: " + currentTd.text());
                }`